# Finite difference basic operation to solve boundary value problem

Tags: finite-differences

I got a question regarding finite difference method to solve boundary value problem on second order derivative equation.
This is taken from the "Numerical Methods using MATLAB" by Mathews & Fink.
This is the problem from the book:

> Solve the boundary value problem:
>
> $x^{''}(t) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}x^{'}(t)-\frac{2}{1+t^2}x(t)+1$
>
> with $x(0)=1.25$ and $x(4)=−0.95$ over the interval $[0, 4]$.

We're supposed to use the following equations to solve it:

> $x^{''}(t) = p(t)x^{'}(t) + q(t)x(t) + r(t)$
>
> $(\frac{-h}{2}p_j -1)x_{j-1}+(2+h^2q_j)x_j+(\frac{h}{2}p_j -1)x_{j+1}=-h^2 r_j$

The book only gives the $x_j$ calculation result in a table without any step-by-step calculation. I understand that $x_1=1.25$  but I cannot get the result for $x_2$, $x_3$, etc.

How do we calculate $x_j$ using the formula, if we don't know $x_{j+1}$ ?
The information given is only for the initial and end value of $x$, but we need $x_{3}$ to calculate $x_{2}$.

Please find the screenshot from the book below:
[image: Problem & result table]

Comment: A more detailed screenshot of the book & formula can be seen here https://imgur.com/a/GR7yiCJ

Comment: Could you post the actual finite difference scheme you want to use?